# Getting ID of next neigbour using nngeo (nn_st)

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I need to calculate the nearest distance between objects (schools). I have two sf-data-frames (sf_special and sf_no_special). I used the nngeo package and the nn_st command, which worked fine! The output of nn_st is a) the distance between the two closest schools and b) the index of the nearest school. The index of the nearest school does not help me to identify the school. What I want is the School-ID (id). How can I retrieve this information using the index of the nearest neighbor? Here are my code and same data-examples:

```
ata01 <- read.delim2('0708.txt',header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ".")

data01$sps[is.na(data01$sps)]<-0


special <- subset(data01, sps == 1,
                  select=c(id, geo, sps, lon, lat))
no_special <- subset(data01, sps == 0,
                     select=c(id, geo, sps, lon, lat))


sf_special <- st_as_sf(special,
                       coords = c("lon", "lat"), # x, y (order matters)
                       crs = 4326)

sf_no_special <- st_as_sf(no_special,
                          coords = c("lon", "lat"), # x, y (order matters)
                          crs = 4326)



nearest <- st_nn(sf_special,sf_no_special, k = 1, returnDist = T,  progress = FALSE)


special$dist = nn_dist$dist
special$n = nn_dist$nn
```

Now the Output looks like this:

```
    id                                          geo sps      lon      lat     dist  n
8  23880 Blankartstr. 13;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler   1 7.102950 50.54219 2088.908  6
32 14176          Siegener Str. 26;57610;Altenkirchen   1 7.651246 50.68972 918.4893 30
35 26147        Johannes-Krell-Str. 17;57518;Betzdorf   1 7.851260 50.79092 589.7386 52
45 13408                 Schulstr.;57580;Gebhardshain   1 7.823415 50.74588 3302.691 48
46 10435              Martin-Luther-Str. 4;57577;Hamm   1 7.669567 50.76203 2005.314 38
62 23954                   Schulstr. 10;67577;Alsheim   1 8.335559 49.76163 3584.156 68
```

Two questions:

1. Instead of n(index of next school from "nearest"), I want the ID of the nearest school! How can I use the index to retrieve information like the school-ID? The school ID is stored in sf_no_special but the index of nearest and sf_no_special do not match!
2. I also want to create a variable that contains the number of schools within a radius of 1,5km. I can use the nn_st command to get the distance to the nearest j schools and then I need to sum the schools where dist < 1.500. Any suggestions? I tried:

```
num.1500 <- apply(nearest$dist, 1, function(x) {
  sum(x < 1500)
})
```

But I did get the error:

```
Error in apply(nearest$dist, 1, function(x) { : 
  dim(X) muss positive Länge haben
```

Here is an example of my data:

```
> dput(droplevels(data01[1:10, ]))
structure(list(typ = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Grundschule", class = "factor"), id = c(11725L, 
11739L, 26883L, 11863L, 11996L, 12060L, 22062L, 23880L, 12237L, 
12630L), str = structure(c(7L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 
6L), .Label = c("Ahrstr. 87", "Blankartstr. 13", "Eichenbacher Weg 26", 
"Kesslinger Str. 1", "Koblenzer Str.", "Quellenstr. 15", "Schulstr.", 
"Schulstr. 5", "Vehner Weg 31", "Weststr. 27"), class = "factor"), 
    plz = c(53518L, 53506L, 53505L, 53533L, 53498L, 53474L, 53474L, 
    53474L, 53505L, 56656L), ort = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("Adenau", "Ahrbrück", 
    "Altenahr", "Antweiler", "Bad Breisig", "Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", 
    "Berg", "Brohl-Lützing"), class = "factor"), geo = structure(c(8L, 
    4L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("Ahrstr. 87;53505;Berg", 
    "Blankartstr. 13;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", "Eichenbacher Weg 26;53533;Antweiler", 
    "Kesslinger Str. 1;53506;Ahrbrück", "Koblenzer Str.;53498;Bad Breisig", 
    "Quellenstr. 15;56656;Brohl-Lützing", "Schulstr. 5;53505;Altenahr", 
    "Schulstr.;53518;Adenau", "Vehner Weg 31;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", 
    "Weststr. 27;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler"), class = "factor"), 
    jahr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = "2007/08", class = "factor"), name = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = "GS Ahrweiler", class = "factor"), 
    start = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA
    ), .Label = "2001/02", class = "factor"), sps = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), lon = c(6.9325459, 6.97516, 6.9875745, 
    6.825407, 7.3035599, 7.1322642, 7.1809, 7.10295, 6.93609, 
    7.32739), lat = c(50.382685, 50.48649, 50.5085722, 50.406783, 
    50.5055535, 50.5441126, 50.54013, 50.54219, 50.52239, 50.48599
    ), dist = list(2088.90766536052, 918.489268082922, 589.738579014495, 
        3302.69115170858, 2005.31411895232, 3584.15570982643, 
        366.260782140767, 2694.12065272956, 5257.32234958339, 
        1700.27776226661), n = list(6L, 30L, 52L, 48L, 38L, 68L, 
        58L, 84L, 142L, 138L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
> 


> dput(droplevels(special[1:10, ]))
structure(list(id = c(23880L, 14176L, 26147L, 13408L, 10435L, 
23954L, 20647L, 26447L, 15617L, 23173L), geo = structure(c(2L, 
9L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("Beindestr.;55569;Monzingen", 
"Blankartstr. 13;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", "Donnersbergstr. 32;55232;Alzey", 
"Johannes-Krell-Str. 17;57518;Betzdorf", "Martin-Luther-Str. 4;57577;Hamm", 
"Schulstr. 10;67577;Alsheim", "Schulstr.;55593;Rüdesheim", "Schulstr.;57580;Gebhardshain", 
"Siegener Str. 26;57610;Altenkirchen", "Weinstr. 79;67169;Kallstadt"
), class = "factor"), sps = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    lon = c(7.10295, 7.6512462, 7.85126, 7.8234146, 7.6695674, 
    8.3355588, 8.1119607, 8.17405, 7.5906339, 7.8107492), lat = c(50.54219, 
    50.6897185, 50.79092, 50.7458834, 50.7620283, 49.7616261, 
    49.7408171, 49.49098, 49.7968555, 49.8468627), dist = list(
        2088.90766536052, 918.489268082922, 589.738579014495, 
        3302.69115170858, 2005.31411895232, 3584.15570982643, 
        366.260782140767, 2694.12065272956, 5257.32234958339, 
        1700.27776226661), n = list(6L, 30L, 52L, 48L, 38L, 68L, 
        58L, 84L, 142L, 138L)), row.names = c(8L, 32L, 35L, 45L, 
46L, 62L, 63L, 109L, 143L, 148L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(droplevels(no_special[1:10, ]))
structure(list(id = c(11725L, 11739L, 26883L, 11863L, 11996L, 
12060L, 22062L, 12237L, 12630L, 26537L), geo = structure(c(8L, 
4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("Ahrstr. 87;53505;Berg", 
"Eichenbacher Weg 26;53533;Antweiler", "Greimerstalweg 19;56659;Burgbrohl", 
"Kesslinger Str. 1;53506;Ahrbrück", "Koblenzer Str.;53498;Bad Breisig", 
"Quellenstr. 15;56656;Brohl-Lützing", "Schulstr. 5;53505;Altenahr", 
"Schulstr.;53518;Adenau", "Vehner Weg 31;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", 
"Weststr. 27;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler"), class = "factor"), 
    sps = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lon = c(6.9325459, 
    6.97516, 6.9875745, 6.825407, 7.3035599, 7.1322642, 7.1809, 
    6.93609, 7.32739, 7.27089), lat = c(50.382685, 50.48649, 
    50.5085722, 50.406783, 50.5055535, 50.5441126, 50.54013, 
    50.52239, 50.48599, 50.45707)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks for helping!

edit2: (expected output)

```
head(special)
   id                                          geo sps      lon      lat     dist  n     ID     Radius-1500
8  23880 Blankartstr. 13;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler   1 7.102950 50.54219 2088.908  6
32 14176          Siegener Str. 26;57610;Altenkirchen   1 7.651246 50.68972 918.4893 30
35 26147        Johannes-Krell-Str. 17;57518;Betzdorf   1 7.851260 50.79092 589.7386 52
45 13408                 Schulstr.;57580;Gebhardshain   1 7.823415 50.74588 3302.691 48
46 10435              Martin-Luther-Str. 4;57577;Hamm   1 7.669567 50.76203 2005.314 38
62 23954                   Schulstr. 10;67577;Alsheim   1 8.335559 49.76163 3584.156 68
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure that I understand the first question but why can't you simply extract the row corresponding to the nearest neighbour? Something like `sf_no_special[nearest$nn[[1]], "id"]`

Comment: @agila This is what I need! How can I loop this over all the cases and bind the output to the data.frame "special"? I'm sorry, total beginner -.-

Comment: What do mean by "loop over all the cases"? You want to repeat the same operation for the three dataframes you provided?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. In my first post you can see my output (dataframe "special"). Variable dist is the distance to the next school and n is the index of the "neigbour". Instead of the index, I need the ID. So for every "special school" I need to attach the dist and ID of the neighbor. The list "nearest" holds this information (index/dist). So i guess, to find the ID for all schools, i need to loop your code. I also want to create a radius-variable, which gives me the number of schools within a radius of 1,5km. So far i could not find a solution for this.

Comment: Sorry for the super slow replies, it was a crazy busy day yesterday. Anyway my question was related to the fact that you provide three data frame. The first one has 1 special and 9 no-special school, the second one has 10 special schools, and the third one has 10 non-special school. You want to find the nn for all special schools in the second dataframe wrt to the third dataframe, right?

Comment: @agila Thanks for helping anyways! I want to find the distance/ID of next neighbor for each special school. I edited my first post. I Also want to calculate a Variable, which gives me the number of schools within a radius of 15,km!: To Answer your question I want to find the nn (id) for all nonspecial schools in the third data frame and wrt to the second data frame. For year special school the dist/id to the next neighbor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following code since I'm still not 100% sure that I understood your questions. First I need to load some packages:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(nngeo)
library(tmap) # for the final map
```

and data

```r
special <- structure(
  list(
    id = c(
      23880L, 14176L, 26147L, 13408L, 10435L, 23954L, 20647L, 26447L, 15617L, 23173L
    ), 
    geo = structure(
      c(
       2L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 7L
      ), 
      .Label = c(
        "Beindestr.;55569;Monzingen", "Blankartstr. 13;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", 
        "Donnersbergstr. 32;55232;Alzey", "Johannes-Krell-Str. 17;57518;Betzdorf", 
        "Martin-Luther-Str. 4;57577;Hamm", "Schulstr. 10;67577;Alsheim", 
        "Schulstr.;55593;Rudesheim", "Schulstr.;57580;Gebhardshain", 
        "Siegener Str. 26;57610;Altenkirchen", "Weinstr. 79;67169;Kallstadt"
      ), 
      class = "factor"
    ), 
    sps = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    lon = c(
      7.10295, 7.6512462, 7.85126, 7.8234146, 7.6695674, 8.3355588, 8.1119607, 
      8.17405, 7.5906339, 7.8107492
    ), 
    lat = c(
      50.54219, 50.6897185, 50.79092, 50.7458834, 50.7620283, 49.7616261, 
      49.7408171, 49.49098, 49.7968555, 49.8468627
    ), 
    dist = list(
      2088.90766536052, 918.489268082922, 589.738579014495, 3302.69115170858, 
      2005.31411895232, 3584.15570982643, 366.260782140767, 2694.12065272956, 
      5257.32234958339, 1700.27776226661
    ), 
    n = list(6L, 30L, 52L, 48L, 38L, 68L, 58L, 84L, 142L, 138L)
  ), 
  row.names = c(8L, 32L, 35L, 45L, 46L, 62L, 63L, 109L, 143L, 148L), 
  class = "data.frame"
)

# input data for "no-special"
no_special <- structure(
  list(
    id = c(
      11725L, 11739L, 26883L, 11863L, 11996L, 12060L, 22062L, 12237L, 12630L, 26537L
    ), 
    geo = structure(
      c(8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 3L), 
      .Label = c(
        "Ahrstr. 87;53505;Berg", "Eichenbacher Weg 26;53533;Antweiler", 
        "Greimerstalweg 19;56659;Burgbrohl", "Kesslinger Str. 1;53506;Ahrbruck", 
        "Koblenzer Str.;53498;Bad Breisig", "Quellenstr. 15;56656;Brohl-Lutzing", 
        "Schulstr. 5;53505;Altenahr", "Schulstr.;53518;Adenau", 
         "Vehner Weg 31;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", "Weststr. 27;53474;Bad Neuenahr Ahrweiler"
      ), 
      class = "factor"
    ), 
    sps = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    lon = c(
      6.9325459, 6.97516, 6.9875745, 6.825407, 7.3035599, 7.1322642, 7.1809, 
      6.93609, 7.32739, 7.27089
    ), 
    lat = c(
      50.382685, 50.48649, 50.5085722, 50.406783, 50.5055535, 50.5441126, 
      50.54013, 50.52239, 50.48599, 50.45707
    )
  ), 
  row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L), 
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

Then I need to transform data into `sf` objects:

```r
sf_special <- st_as_sf(
  special,
  coords = c("lon", "lat"), # x, y (order matters)
  crs = 4326
)
sf_no_special <- st_as_sf(
  no_special, 
  coords = c("lon", "lat"), # x, y (order matters)
  crs = 4326
)
```

Find the nearest neighbours between all special and all non-special

```r
nearest <- st_nn(sf_special, sf_no_special, k = 1, returnDist = FALSE, progress = FALSE)
#> lon-lat points
```

Check the result

```r
nearest
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 9
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 10
```

That output means that the nearest neigh between the first school in `sf_special` and the schools in `sf_no_special` is the 6th school in `sf_no_special`. The same idea applies to all the other indices. We can extract the `sf_no_special` IDs as follows:

```r
sf_no_special[unlist(nearest), "id", drop = TRUE]
#>  [1] 12060 11996 11996 11996 11996 12630 26537 26537 26537 26537
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "integer"
```

and append that information to sf_special

```r
sf_special$ID <- sf_no_special[unlist(nearest), "id", drop = TRUE]
```

Check the result

```r
sf_special
#> Simple feature collection with 10 features and 6 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 7.10295 ymin: 49.49098 xmax: 8.335559 ymax: 50.79092
#> geographic CRS: WGS 84
#>        id                                          geo sps     dist   n
#> 8   23880 Blankartstr. 13;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler   1 2088.908   6
#> 32  14176          Siegener Str. 26;57610;Altenkirchen   1 918.4893  30
#> 35  26147        Johannes-Krell-Str. 17;57518;Betzdorf   1 589.7386  52
#> 45  13408                 Schulstr.;57580;Gebhardshain   1 3302.691  48
#> 46  10435              Martin-Luther-Str. 4;57577;Hamm   1 2005.314  38
#> 62  23954                   Schulstr. 10;67577;Alsheim   1 3584.156  68
#> 63  20647               Donnersbergstr. 32;55232;Alzey   1 366.2608  58
#> 109 26447                  Weinstr. 79;67169;Kallstadt   1 2694.121  84
#> 143 15617                   Beindestr.;55569;Monzingen   1 5257.322 142
#> 148 23173                    Schulstr.;55593;Rudesheim   1 1700.278 138
#>                      geometry    ID
#> 8    POINT (7.10295 50.54219) 12060
#> 32  POINT (7.651246 50.68972) 11996
#> 35   POINT (7.85126 50.79092) 11996
#> 45  POINT (7.823415 50.74588) 11996
#> 46  POINT (7.669567 50.76203) 11996
#> 62  POINT (8.335559 49.76163) 12630
#> 63  POINT (8.111961 49.74082) 26537
#> 109  POINT (8.17405 49.49098) 26537
#> 143 POINT (7.590634 49.79686) 26537
#> 148 POINT (7.810749 49.84686) 26537
```

If you want to check how many non-special schools are within 15km from each special school we can use `st_is_within_distance`

```r
no_special_within_radius <- st_is_within_distance(
  x = sf_special, 
  y = sf_no_special, 
  dist = units::set_units(15, "km")
)
no_special_within_radius
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 10, where the predicate was `is_within_distance'
#>  1: 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8
#>  2: (empty)
#>  3: (empty)
#>  4: (empty)
#>  5: (empty)
#>  6: (empty)
#>  7: (empty)
#>  8: (empty)
#>  9: (empty)
#>  10: (empty)
```

The output means that the schools 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 and 8 in `sf_no_special` are within 15km from the first school in `sf_special`. The other schools are too far from their neighbours. We can count the schools using the function lengths and add that information to `sf_special`:

```r
sf_special$within_radius <- lengths(no_special_within_radius)
```

Check the result:

```r
sf_special
#> Simple feature collection with 10 features and 7 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 7.10295 ymin: 49.49098 xmax: 8.335559 ymax: 50.79092
#> geographic CRS: WGS 84
#>        id                                          geo sps     dist   n
#> 8   23880 Blankartstr. 13;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler   1 2088.908   6
#> 32  14176          Siegener Str. 26;57610;Altenkirchen   1 918.4893  30
#> 35  26147        Johannes-Krell-Str. 17;57518;Betzdorf   1 589.7386  52
#> 45  13408                 Schulstr.;57580;Gebhardshain   1 3302.691  48
#> 46  10435              Martin-Luther-Str. 4;57577;Hamm   1 2005.314  38
#> 62  23954                   Schulstr. 10;67577;Alsheim   1 3584.156  68
#> 63  20647               Donnersbergstr. 32;55232;Alzey   1 366.2608  58
#> 109 26447                  Weinstr. 79;67169;Kallstadt   1 2694.121  84
#> 143 15617                   Beindestr.;55569;Monzingen   1 5257.322 142
#> 148 23173                    Schulstr.;55593;Rudesheim   1 1700.278 138
#>                      geometry    ID within_radius
#> 8    POINT (7.10295 50.54219) 12060             6
#> 32  POINT (7.651246 50.68972) 11996             0
#> 35   POINT (7.85126 50.79092) 11996             0
#> 45  POINT (7.823415 50.74588) 11996             0
#> 46  POINT (7.669567 50.76203) 11996             0
#> 62  POINT (8.335559 49.76163) 12630             0
#> 63  POINT (8.111961 49.74082) 26537             0
#> 109  POINT (8.17405 49.49098) 26537             0
#> 143 POINT (7.590634 49.79686) 26537             0
#> 148 POINT (7.810749 49.84686) 26537             0
```

We can also plot the schools and check the results graphically:

```r
tmap_mode("view")
#> tmap mode set to interactive viewing

tm_shape(sf_special) + 
  tm_dots() + 
tm_shape(sf_no_special) + 
  tm_dots(col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>